# Bootstrap popover doesn't show

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I want to show popover but I don't see it.

**CODE**

```
echo '
    <a data-toggle="popover" 
       data-trigger="hover" 
       data-html="true" 
       data-placement="top" 
       data-content="HTML MARKUP" 
       class="cf_box popover-extra-balik ' . $this->custom_fields[ 34 ]->name . ' ' . $i->fields[ 34 ] . ' ">
';
echo '<span class="field_value">' . JText::_( 'COM_DJCLASSIFIEDS_EXTRA_BALIK_PREMIUM' ) . '</span>';
echo '</a>';
```

Website Link: [link](https://www.s-autoservis.sk/jazdene-vozidla/aktualna-ponuka?rid=0&se=1&layout=blog&se_cats=1&se_16=Michalovce&se_23=diesel&se_24=AUTOMATICKA&se_26_min=110&se_18=VOLKSWAGEN)

Image: [Image](https://prnt.sc/s29y1t)

Thanks!!

Comment: Please format your code

Answer (score 0):

Add below Javascript in your code.

```
$(function () {
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover()
});
```

**Example**

I removed some PHP code because it's not supported here.

```js
$(function() {
  $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover()
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<a data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="hover" data-html="true" data-placement="top" data-content="<strong>BALÍK PREMIUM obsahuje :</strong>
<ul>
    <li>sezónne pneumatiky</li>
    <li>najbližšiu servisnú prehliadku so zľavou</li>
    <li>dezinfekcia vozidla</li>
    <li>1 x čistenie a doplnenie klimatizácie počas leta zdarma</li>
    <li>povinná výbava zdarma</li>
    <li>zvýhodnené financovanie</li>
</ul>" class="cf_box popover-extra-balik">
  <span class="field_value">BALIK_PREMIUM</span>
</a>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks.You can see result here : 

https://www.s-autoservis.sk/jazdene-vozidla/aktualna-ponuka?rid=0&se=1&layout=blog&se_cats=1&se_16=Michalovce&se_23=diesel&se_24=AUTOMATICKA&se_26_min=110&se_18=VOLKSWAGEN

when i hover on element , script add to element display:none. Why ?
thanks

Comment: Its added via javascript, you need to look your code, where this come from

Comment: I set debugger and I get this result, https://imgur.com/txj4P19, a file called `mootools.core.js` creates that problem

Comment: @RomanHricišin If you like my answer or you got any help from my answer, don't forget to consider up-vote and check this answer as the best answer for you by clicking on the right arrow, thanks!